# Django - Simple select box form vs template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I need to display a simple select input in a template.
This input is based on a selection of objects and should have an selected value.
It will not be used for any post to the server.

```
staffs = Staff.objects.filter(staff__company=comp)
selected_staff = staffs[0]
```

`staffs` are people that I need to display in the selection

I find this input quite verbose so I'm wondering if, instead of writing the input manually in the template, I should take advantage of a little form.

So the question is, should I write the `<option>` input manually or should I use the builtin widget ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a built-in is always better. You can also use `Field.initial` to set an initial value for the field. Documetation is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.initial)

Defining an option and set it on the template (probably using javascript) is much more harder.

UPDATE:

```
class MyStaffForm(forms.Form):
    <your form structure here>
    ...
    <end of your form structure>


def Myview(request):
    ....
    staffs = Staff.objects.filter(staff__company=comp)
    #override form class to add a new form field
    MyStaffForm.base_fields['staff']=forms.ChoiceField(choices=[[(s.id, s) for s in staffs], initial=staff[0].id)
```

This is how you handle the Form Class. But overriding base Form class using `forms.ChoiceField` is not a good choice since you use a queryset for defining choices. So use a `ModelChoiceField` instead

```
MyStaffForm.base_fields['staff']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=staffs, initial=staff[0])
```

Django will handle the rest of the validation and initialization of the form...

Comment: Ok that's kind of what I was thinking. However I don't know exactly how to set the choices from my view which gets the `staffs`

Comment: Second solution: exactly what I was searching for. Thanks